# When we are calculating the cost for implementing a new web application, should we have separate cost for providing the source code to the client

Tags: software-development, cost-management, deliverables, pricing

I am working on a new asp.net core MVC web application as an out sourced senior software developer/architecture. now i did many requirements gathering sessions with the client, and i came our with a detailed requirement and design document, which have been singed by the client. then i break-down the document into tasks and i calculated the total effort for designing,developing,testing and hosting the web application, something as follow:

- Database creation and Design. 50 hours + cost 4,000 USD.
- Developing user registration and profile creation. 10 hours + cost 8,00 USD.
- Developing transaction workflow. 200 hours + cost 16,000 USD.
- tasks for development and hosting and UAT goes on...
- Final. 500 hours + cost 40,000 USD.

so the above cover the full implementation time and cost for the project. but should this covers by defualt giving the client the application source code? or this is not necessary ? and if our client need/ask the source code then we can separately provide costing for it?
Now inside the contract we did not mention anything about transferring the source code, currently we only  include that there will be UAT sessions to deliver the system + 1 year warranty to cover bugs + 10% plus or minus variation/changes based on the singed requirement and design document. but we did not include any thing about delivering the source code to the client.. so should we do so? and is it normal to charge the client extra money for delivering the source code (let say 20% of the total price), beyond the implementation time in our case (500 hours/40,000USD)?

Comment: This is a contract management or legal question, not a project management question within the scope defined by our help center. In the end, this is a business decision your company must base on your market and applicable laws.

Comment: @ToddA.Jacobs Ok i understand your point, but i was asking this question seeking a project management advice, as when we say that a web application will take 5,00 hours + cost 40,000 USD , for designing, developing and hosting it, then usually will this include submitting the source code also?

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question needs to occur before you provided pricing.  Within the contract, you would indicate who owns the what after the what is built.  And then based on that you would price its development accordingly.  So I would advise you not pushing forward the price at which you arrived until you answered this question with your client and get it under contract.  Then re-price your development and then provide to the client.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply.. Yes currently i did not deliver the contract nor the pricing... i am asking this question to clarify things before sending anything.. so usually when we calculate the implementation time -as i did- 500 hours with 40,000 USD (80 USD per hour), this by defualt covers transferring the source code also? second point, if the answer to the first question is No, then is it normal to make 20% extra price to get the source code and copyright?